# How to add image vertical moving animation effect in my android application?

Tags: java, android, animation

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class SplashScreenView extends View {

    private Bitmap icon;
    private int screenW;
    private int screenH;
    private float scale;
    private int iconLocation;
    private Context myContext;
    private Thread thread;



    public SplashScreenView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        myContext = context;
        scale = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap tmpBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.sample_icon);
        icon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmpBitmap, (int)scale*100, (int)scale*100, false);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, (screenW / 2) - (icon.getWidth() / 2), (int) (scale * 10), null);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;
    }


}
```

I want to add a function in my application's splash screen. That is image moving effect from top to center vertically. I don't know how to move this automatically. Let me know how to add moving effect top to center vertically. Thanks! Sorry for my poor english.